# Count div from codility. StackOverflowError in program using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I wrote program for one of lessons from Codility. Its called count div.

For example. I give number 6, 11 and 2. There are 3 numbers from 6 to 11 that we can divide by 2, its 6, 8, 10 so method should return 3.

At first I made program with recursion with only ints but I got error so I changed it to BigIntegers, but it doesnt help at all. It's working good for small numbers but with for example input:

A = 0, B = 20000, K = 1 it gives errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.math.MutableBigInteger.divideKnuth(Unknown Source)
at java.math.MutableBigInteger.divideKnuth(Unknown Source)
at java.math.BigInteger.remainderKnuth(Unknown Source)
at java.math.BigInteger.remainder(Unknown Source)
at java.math.BigInteger.mod(Unknown Source)
at count_div.Solution.bigIntegerSolution(Solution.java:29)
at count_div.Solution.bigIntegerSolution(Solution.java:35)
```

Here's my code:

```
public int solution(int A, int B, int K){

    BigInteger minValue = BigInteger.valueOf(A);
    BigInteger maxValue = BigInteger.valueOf(B);
    BigInteger div = BigInteger.valueOf(K);

    finalCounter = bigIntegerSolution(minValue, maxValue, div).intValue();

    return finalCounter;
}

public BigInteger bigIntegerSolution(BigInteger minValue, BigInteger maxValue, BigInteger div){

    int comparator = minValue.compareTo(maxValue);

    if(comparator <= 0){

        BigInteger modValue = minValue.mod(div);

        if( modValue.compareTo(zero) == 0){
            divCounter = divCounter.add(one);
        }
        minValue = minValue.add(one);
        bigIntegerSolution(minValue, maxValue, div);
    }

    return divCounter;
}
```

Is there anything I can do or my solution idea is just bad for this purpose? I know that they are other solutions but I first came up with this and I would like to know if I can fix it.

Comment: You want us to replace your recursive algorithm with non-recursive one. It is not always trivial problem, so you have to do it without assistance

Comment: I don't want you to replace my algorithm. I would like to do this exercise with recursive if it is possible and I'm asking if there is something in my method that causes stackoverflow error. I wrote at the end of my post that I know that they are other solutions for this problem but I would like to know why my solution doesnt work and/or why this solution is bad.

Comment: Can I ask why you need recursion for this? The problem you're hitting (which I think you've already identified) is that for every call to `bigIntegerSolution`, you're adding another item to the stack, and 20,000 entries is too many. You could increase the stack size (Google will tell you how), but you'll always hit a limit. Why is recursion better here than just a normal for loop, from `minValue` to `maxValue`?

Comment: I also solved this with math. Has anyone solved it with prefix sum? I thought that was the point of that codility section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recursion is not a great choice for this problem because you really don't have a lot of state to store as you move through the numbers. Each time you increase the range by one you increase the depth by one. Hence your stack overflow errors for a large range.

You don't need BigInteger for this: it's the depth of the stack not the size of the variables that's causing the issue.

Here is a solution using recursion:

```
int divisorsInRange(int min, int max, int div) {
    if (min > max)
        return 0;
    else
        return (min % div == 0 ? 1 : 0) + divisorsInRange(min + 1, max, div);
}
```

Non-recursive solutions are really much simpler and more efficient. For example, using Java 8 streams:

```
return IntStream.range(min, max).filter(n -> n % div == 0).count();
```

However you can also solve this without any loops or streams.

EDIT1: Wrong solution, though seems to be correct and elegant. Check `min = 16, max =342, div = 17` mentioned by @Bopsi below:

```
int countDivisors(int min, int max, int div) {
    int count = (max - min) / div;
    if (min % div == 0 || max % div == 0)
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

EDIT2: Correct solution:

```
int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
    const int firstDividableInRange = A % K == 0 ? A : A + (K - A % K);
    const int lastDividableInRange = B - B % K;
    const int result = (lastDividableInRange - firstDividableInRange) / K + 1;

return result;
}
```

Comment: None of the solutions meet complexity requirements for this exercise:
Complexity:

        expected worst-case time complexity is O(1);
        expected worst-case space complexity is O(1).

Comment: fails with min = 16, max 342, and div = 17

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is out of initial requirements

> Complexity:
>
> expected worst-case time complexity is O(1); 
>   expected worst-case space complexity is O(1).

One line solution

```
public class CountDiv {
    public int solution(int a, int b, int k) {
        return b / k - a / k + (a % k == 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

[Test results](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingU6ZTVE-CYF/)

Comment: Can you please explain why did you write this solution? Let say i am asking from the perspective of interviewer.

Comment: It is prefix-sum @ZeeshanShabbir, 
B is the upper bound, and A is the lower bound.

first, you count all the divisor available from 1 to upper bound by  B/K
then you count all the divisor available from 1 to lower bound by A/K

Then you use B/K - A/K, you will get all the divisor from A to B

But wait, what if A divisible by K, then you will count it 2 times (from A and from B) then you need to check it to make sure it is only counted once.

Answer (score 2):

Brevity is ruby. This also gets 100%

```rb
def solution(a, b, k)
  b / k - (a - 1) / k
end
```

This answer makes use of the fact that ruby will automatically round down the quotient of 2 integers, returning an integer result.

Let's use the original example, a = 6, b = 11, k = 2

- `11 / 2 = 5` - total number of ways 11 is evenly divisible by 2.
- `(6 - 1) / 2 = 2` - number of ways ints `<` 6 are evenly divisible by 2 (to exclude from total).
- `5 - 2 = 3` - subtract the excluded count from the total to get our result.

This works with python's floor division too:

```py
def solution(A, B, K):
    return B // K - (A - 1) // K
```

Comment: It's more helpful if you explain your answer

Comment: Good point @AndresGardiol - on reviewing this I realised that I didn't need to call `.ceil` after all. This shortened algorithm still gets 100% on codility.

Comment: I like this solution and explaination but I get some answers wrong (got 0, expected 1) for test case A = B in {0,1}, K = 11, and other case where A is 0. You may need to account for A being 0 and how to handle. (Debatable if 0 should count but I guess they count it)

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time following some of the answers here, even though they are more elegant. But this solution allowed me to reason about the problem better, maybe it helps you.

The basic idea is to shift the 'A' and 'B' values until they line up with the 'K' divisibility. That is, we move A & B until both (A % K == 0) and (B % K == 0).

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
        // shift A up
        while (A % K != 0) {
            A++;
        }

        // shift B down
        while (B % K != 0) {
            B--;
        }

        return (B - A) / K + 1;
    }
}
```

It could also be done without the while loops, just incrementing A by the mod amount, and decrementing B by the K-mod amount.

Comment: You did a good job!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem using arithmetic progression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression). I've had to add a special case for 0, which I can't explain but it was based on the test results:

```
if (K > B)
    return A == 0 ? 1 : 0;

int min = A >= K ? A + A % K : K;
int max = B - (B % K);

// an = a1 + (n − 1) * ⋅r
return (max - min + K) / K + (A == 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The bigger your `B` value, the more `BigIntegers` will be stored in your machine memory. That is why, it works fine with small values, and does not work with big ones. So, recursion is a bad solution to solve this kind of a problem, because you are trying to store too many values in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is (100/100) solution  in Java.

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
        int result;
        int toAdd = 0;
        int lowerBound = 0;
        int upperBound = 0;
        if (A % K == 0) {
            lowerBound = A;
            toAdd = 1;
        } else {
            lowerBound = A - A % K + K;
            if ((lowerBound - A % K) >= 0 ) {
                toAdd = 1;
            }
        }

        if (B % K == 0) {
            upperBound = B;
        } else {
            upperBound = B - B % K;
        }

        result = (upperBound - lowerBound) / K + toAdd;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the code comments to get clear picture

```
public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        int count = 0;

        start = (A % K == 0)? A : ((A / K)* K ) + K; //minimum divisible by K in the range
        end = (B % K == 0)? B : B - (B % K); // maximum divisible by K in the range

        count = ((end - start) / K) + 1; //no of divisibles by K inside the range start & end

        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Idea is that I'm looking for first number that can be divided on `K` after that number of divisibles in range is `((B - first) / K) + 1`. We need to know difference between biggest limit (which is `B`) and first divisible and count how many `K` can be fit between them because firs number won't be included we need to add one for correct result.

```
class Solution {

    public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
        if (A == B) {
            if (A % K == 0) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
        int first = (A % K == 0) ? A : A + (K - (A % K));
        if (A != 0 && (first > B || first == 0)) return 0;

        return ((B - first) / K) + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is mine :)

```
public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
    int numEl = 0;
    int first = A;
    while(numEl == 0 && first <= B) {
        if(first%K == 0) {
            numEl += 1;
        } else
           first += 1;
    }
    numEl += (B - first)/K;
    return numEl;
}
```